# Change the width of the cell content in java using PDFCell

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Hi I have an app which generates PDF page using java iText, for a single column the width is changing so some times if there are more than 16 character the rest of the character go below in the PDF page 
For Example I have a customer Acct which varies from 10 - 16 characters it appears like on my PDF page like

```
GW1BKCADT402814  
1
```

instead i need it on the same line GW1BKCADT4028141.
The last character goes below in that column.

```
PdfPTable tTable = new PdfPTable( 13 );        
PdfPCell c1 = PDFConstants.getDefaultPdfPCell( PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, 2 );    
c1.setPhrase( new Phrase( new Chunk( t.getCustomerAcc(), StyleConstantsPDF.FONT_NORAMAL_8 ) ));    
tTable.addCell( c1 );
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample please? Right now, I have no clue as to what it is you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Seems like you didn't define the width of your column in a way that the content fits. How are you creating the `PdfPTable` and the `PdfPCell`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have this code, can you help me out

Comment: You have a table with 13 columns. You don't define the widths of the columns. You're only adding one cell. Your code is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Help yourself and *follow my advice!* Define the widths of the columns! I don't see you doing that anywhere in your code. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31155569/1622493 for an example.